# Textbox event handlers in Visual web developer

Tags: html, vb.net, textbox, visual-web-developer

I'm having a bit of problems working with a few textboxes. All i want to do is have my second textbox clear when i change the text in my first textbox.
Generally when i try this it only happens on postback, is there a way to do it without it having to postback for each character typed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the [AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback(v=vs.85).aspx) property to true. [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c(v=vs.85).aspx) an example.

Comment: My issue with this, is when I hit the OK button on my form, that code fires before the one that compares the two text boxes and it comes out nil. I'd like it to only come out nil when i change the text in the first textbox.